# Remove css and scripts from PartialView

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to implement an Star Rating code. For that I am using a PartialView called as:

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("Rate"); }
```

The purpose is to show and handle the star rating code separately from the current page. Thus, I dont really need to use the css or other javascripts that are being rendered in the parent .cshtml.

I am removing the layout as follow:

```
@{ Layout = null; }
```

From the controller:

```
public ActionResult Rate() {
return PartialView(); }
```

But I noticed that the parent css and javascript are messing up with the star rating thus I don't really want to use them. How to protect the partial view?

Comment: Include a specific css file for styling the elements in the partial (but include it in the main view)

Comment: The problem is e.g. The parent in the css has in the stylesheet a formatting for 'a'. The partialview Star Rating also as a stylesheet for 'a'. I think is really uncessary to be declaring '!important'. A better way is to just dont really use the parent css nor scripts.

Comment: If your partial view is enclosed in an element (say) `<div id="ratings">` then in the css file `#ratings a { color: red; }` to override the color set in the other style sheet (so long as this one is loaded after the other one, the styles will be overridden - no need for `!important`. But do not put a style sheet in a partial (only in the main view or a layout)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to explain why it won't work is to illustrate it with my rusty paint skills...

[image]

---

Remember, a `PartialView` is just another `HTML` template that's best utilized for content that repeats on your website, for instance, imagine you're developing a blog, and you've structured how you want the comments on a post to look, you would take that `HTML` content and place it in a `_CommentsPartial.cshtml` `PartialView`. Whilst placing all the CSS styling in an actual CSS file that is referenced in the root `_Layout.cshtml` file.

The `PartialView` would then be rendered for each individual comment on your blog.  Same principle applies to your stars...